# Is there a way to direct category list links to a specific page with category variable in URL?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a dropdown list of all categories, but have it directed to a specific page (not the default category page) with the variable in the URL, i.e. "?page=50&cat=3".

So far, I've only found functions that have the link to "?cat=3" built in, so it defaults to the category page, rather than a specified page. What's the best way to do what I want?

Edit: Essentially, I need an array of category names and their respective IDs.

Comment: is it because you want to have a separate template for category?

Comment: I'm going to be eventually using AJAX to display all sorts of filtered results on the same page so I want to be able to construct queries manually.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a separate template ( refer word press for creating a template file), assign that template to new page.

You can get the page id easily for the template and while showing drop down, you can link all the categories to that page, so when you click over the link, you would get the category using,

```
 get_query_var or from $_GET
```

And then whatever you want to achieve, you can add your custom code in the template for that category.

You can fetch categories using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

```
get_categories();
```